# Как максимально быстро получить значения с базы данных

Tags: c#, sql-server

Собственно есть база данных, с которой работаю при помощи ADO.NET, в базу данных постоянно добавляются новые значения, обновляются, берутся и удаляются. Возникает проблема с временем выполнения получения значений (время на добавление новых записей, удаления и редактирования занимает меньше 100 мс) а вот время получения могут достигать от 1 до 5000 мс. Использую пул подключений.
Пример функции которая получает значение с бд:

```
    public string GetRequest(string id)
    {
        string requestbody = "";
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Program.connectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [PTable] WHERE [Id]=@Id", sqlConnection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", id);

            using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    requestbody = sqlReader.GetString(5);
                }
            }
        }
        return requestbody;
    }
```

Я думаю что вся проблема кроется в SqlDataReader, но каким образом и какие пути решения без понятия, в таблице 13 столбцов, количество строк от 1 до 200, в в некоторых ячейках хранятся html страницы

Comment: Т. к. берется значение только одной колонки (пятой) - `GetString(5)` - то вместо `*` нужно указать именно эту колонку в `SELECT`. Далее, т. к. берется значение только из одной строки, то следует использовать `ExecuteScalar` вместо `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: вы пробовали этот запрос выполнить, ну например в MS SQL Studio, что  по времени получается? План запроса смотрели? Блокировки во время выполнения запроса?

Comment: Кроме того, у метода `ExecuteReader` есть перегрузка, в которой можно указать дополнительные опции, но в вашем случае это не очень нужно, а вот от `SELECT * ...` действительно нужно избавляться.

Comment: блокировки есть только на две функции которые получают данные(всего функций 15), но подсчет времени брался внутри блокировок, а такой момент, если мне нужно взять несколько значений, ExecuteScalar не подойдет же, есть какие то его аналоги? на счет звездочки, заменю на колонку и посмотрим что будет

Comment: Про блокировки, я имел ввиду, что запрос может висеть ожидая завершения другого запроса, поставившего блокировку

Comment: Найдите те ID, на которых тормозит, и посмотрите план запроса. В самом ExecuteReader  тормозить нечему, скорее всего тормозит именно вызов SQL. Стоит взять профайлер SQL и посмотреть что происходит. Блокировки в коде на функции получения данных скорее всего излишни - целостность у вас все равно обеспечивается самим SQL Server.

Comment: Если тормозит на разных ID, случайным образом - нужно посмотреть статистику ожиданий на SQL Server (https://www.brentozar.com/sql/wait-stats/) и решать конкретную проблему. Если это блокировки при чтении из-за одновременной записи - то [включение READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT решит проблему](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server).

Comment: Возможно дело на стороне sql,а именно в разной селективности @id. Почитай вот здесь http://www.queryprocessor.ru/disable_parameter_sniffing/#more-1248

Answer (score 1):

Для того, что бы ответить на данные вопросы:

1. Есть ли у вас индекс на поле по которому выполняется фильтрация?
2. Нужны ли вам все колонки при выборе или нужны какие-то конкретные? Это понизит сетевой трафик.
3. Нет ли проблемы с сетью? Ведь тянув большое кол-во данных на сторону клиента, узким местом может быть сеть.

Comment: Да, выборка идет по уникальному айди, нужны не все колонки, сервер локальный